# Should we give new Token to each user when 2 users logins with same credentials in webapi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, access-token

what happens when 2 users logins with same credentials in token based authentication in webapi.
Should i give different token to each user or same token to both user.

Comment: I'd say they are separate sessions so each should get their own token.

Comment: Ideally, Token generation end-point will generate different token for each request, It does not matter which/same credential you use.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by "2 users".

It could be 2 different users or the same user connecting twice.
Given the fact those two users have used the same credentials, I think they should have the same token.